# How do I integrate a curve numerically in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I do numerical integration of a vector in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861042/how-do-i-do-numerical-integration-of-a-vector-in-matlab)

I have an `x-y` dataset (see figure) but I don't have the fundamental function of the data, so I can't use symbolic integration. Is there an easy way to integrate the curve numerically?

The only way I can think of is a `for` loop over evey y-value times the delta x between two points next to each other? Are there other ways to do it?

[image]

Comment: check out the [TRAPZ](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/trapz.html) function: `trapz(X,Y)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be looking at an integration scheme like Runge-Kutta or Burlish-Stoer.  You'll want something that uses a variable increment so you can use a larger step where the function is flat and a smaller one to capture those peaks.

Comment: It sounds like the original poster has his function in the form of sampled data, in which case this won't work.

Comment: It can work if he selects the points appropriately.  Why insist on looping over lots of points when nothing is changing?  It's entirely possible.

Answer (score 3):

[`trapz`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/trapz.html) is probably what you are looking for:

> TRAPZ  Trapezoidal numerical integration.
>
> ```
> Z = TRAPZ(X,Y) computes the integral of Y with respect to X using
> the trapezoidal method.  X and Y must be vectors of the same
> length, or X must be a column vector and Y an array whose first
> non-singleton dimension is length(X).  TRAPZ operates along this
> dimension.
> ```